# Execution failed Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I can't build my project, the error I get is:

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong:
>        Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
>     com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/home/yanivs/Android/Sdk/build-tools/23.0.2/aapt'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

I have tried all the answers I could find here, none of them worked.

Comment: Already tried reinstalling Android Studio + Android SDK (after uninstalling, of course)?